# postgresql-epoch conversion from string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help in converting string which is in the format of YYYYMMdd string to AMERICAN CST, but currently by default it's converting to GMT. not sure how to fix this, any suggestions on this.

```
select case when trim(end_dt)='00010101' then 0
            else extract(epoch from to_date(end_dt,'YYYYMMDD'))*1000
       end as end_date
from tbl;
```

Comment: Why do you store a date as a string, and not as a date? But a date doesn't have a time zone either, not sure how you want to fix that when it doesn't exist. For a timestamp you can use AT TIME ZONE 'your time zone'

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are creating a `date` much less a `timestamp`, you are just converting `epoch` to milliseconds. Nowhere do I see a conversion that would result in a time zone. Given that `epoch` is based on UTC it would not be surprising that when you did convert it that it would be in UTC.

Comment: The correct solution is to alter the column's data type to `date`